# ggplot2 draws two legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I have almost complete the following graph, but there is one problem with it.

The legend in the graph is drawn twice.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(Period = c("January 1997 - August 2003", "September 2003 - Jun 2005", 
"Jul 2005 - Dec 2009", "January 1997 - August 2003", "September 2003 - Jun 2005", 
"Jul 2005 - Dec 2009"), Time.Period = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan 1997 - Aug 2003", "Jul 2005 - Dec 2009", 
 "Sep 2003 - Jun 2005"), class = "factor"), Variable = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Significant", "Zscore"), class = "factor"), 
 Score = c(8.798129, 4.267268, 7.280275, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64)), .Names = c("Period", 
 "Time.Period", "Variable", "Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))

ggplot(glomor, aes(x=Time.Period, y=Score, group=Variable, shape=Variable, color=Variable)) +
 geom_point() +
 guides(fill=FALSE) +
 scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Jan 1997 - Aug 2003","Sep 2003 - Jun 2005","Jul 2005 - Dec 2009"),    expand=c(.08,0)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Variable), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(size=4.2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,3)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "grey40"), name="", labels=c("Signficant Z-Score",   "Moran's I Z-Score")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="", label=c("Signficant Z-Score", "Moran's I Z-Score")) +
  theme_classic()+
  ylim(0,10) +
  xlab("Time Periods") +
  ylab("Moran's I Z-Score") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(legend.position=c(.75, .85)) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white")) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

Does anyone know, why the ggplot2 produces two legends?

Comment: please use `dput(your_data)` and paste the output.

Comment: in `scale_color` you set the scale name to `""`, but it needs to be the same for both color and shape scales to be merged into one.

Comment: or I believe `guides( guide = "none" )` will also work?

Comment: @Arun I do not have the privileges to paste a picture, which is the output in this case

Comment: @SimonO101 I have tried using guides before, and that was unsuccessful

Comment: `dput(your_data)` is not a picture. `dput` is a command. I'm having a hard time pasting your data in R to try out your code. paste the output of `dput(your_data)` where your_data is the name of your variable.

Comment: @arun sorry for misunderstanding you. That was my fault. I edited the code above, and used dput.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have three aesthetics that are mapped to `Variable`: shape, colour, and linetype. Legends are collapsed together when they have the same title and labels. You have set the title to blank for colour and given it custom labels ("Significant Z-Score" and "Moran's I Z-Score"). You need to do that for linetype and shape as well to get them to collapse all together.

Change

```
scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,3)) +
```

to

```
scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,3), name="", labels=c("Signficant Z-Score",   "Moran's I Z-Score")) +
```

and add

```
scale_shape_discrete(name="", label=c("Signficant Z-Score", "Moran's I Z-Score")) +
```

(You can also get rid of the `scale_fill_discrete` because you don't actually use the fill aesthetic anywhere.)

This gives
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now that is see the answer, it really intuitively makes sense.