# R: ggbiplot legend doesn't show different colours AND shapes

Tags: r, plot, legend, ggbiplot

I admit this question has already been asked at least two times, but none of the provided answers worked for me.

My data is very similar to the ggbiplot `wine` example, so I'll just use this to illustrate my problem.

I want my datapoints to be differently coloured AND shaped, so they look nice when printed in colour but can still be identified when printed in b/w. This actually works just fine, but the legend doesn't play along.

```
require(scales)
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
  groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, var.axes=FALSE) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point(aes(colour=wine.class,shape=wine.class),size=2) +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')
```

produces this: 
[image]

The legend is obviously not what I want. The shapes and colours should be in the same legend.

(As a bonus, I'd also like to remove the small lines from the points, but if that's not easily doable I can live with them. )

I already tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088686/change-point-colors-and-shapes-in-ggbiplot-in-r%20library(ggbiplot)) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend%20library(ggbiplot)).

The first suggestion

```
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
  groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, var.axes=FALSE) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  geom_point(aes(colour = wine.class), size = "2") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(16,17,18)) +

  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')
```

produces this error message (and no plot at all)

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour',
which will replace the existing scale.
Fehler in coords$size * .pt : 
  nicht-numerisches Argument für binären Operator
```

(the last two lines translate to "error in coords$size * .pt : non-numeric argument for binary operator)

The second suggestion

```
  data(wine)
  wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
  ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
    groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, var.axes=FALSE) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Wines",
                        labels = c("barolo","grignolino","barbera"),
                        values = c("blue", "red", "green")) +   
    scale_shape_manual(name = "Wines",
                       labels = c("barolo","grignolino","barbera"),
                       values = c(17,18,19))
```

gives me this error message

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour',
which will replace the existing scale.
```

and a funny plot with coloured ellipses, legend with coloured points, but black datapoints.

I'm afraid my knowledge of R plotting isn't enough to make anything of this. Can someone point me in the right way?

Comment: You need to map `color` and `shape` as you've done and then change the name of the two scales to be the same thing (a la [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15373882/2461552)).   In your first plot you changed the `color` legend name but note the `shape` legend name.  For taking the line out of the legend you can set linetype to 0 in`override.aes` within `guide_legend`.

Comment: Aaahh I feel stupid now. I only looked for ggbiplot topics, not for ggplot. I guess that's why my question was downvoted.. ?

Anyway, this works perfectly, thank you!