# Custom ggplot legend and automatic colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = value,
                             y = ..density..,
                             fill = exp_ID,
                             color = exp_ID)) +      
geom_density(alpha = 0.3,
             bw = 0.5) +
scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.0001,30000)) +
theme_classic(base_size = 15) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black")) +

scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition",
                    breaks=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    labels=c("label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"))
```

Adding a custom legend only gives me two legends. I can't seem to remove the automatic one with e.g. `theme(legend.position="none")`, as this apparently removes both, no matter where it's put in the code.

How do I remove the first legend?

Data here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8piwdBM2UI5Sk03SU1XVUloQ0E

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 draws two legends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370496/ggplot2-draws-two-legends)

Comment: In your link, OP has multiple scale_geoms with different titles, causing each geom to generate a new legend instead of collapsing them. I only have one custom legend, which I had hoped would overwrite the auto-generated legend.

Comment: The checked answer to that question explains things nicely.  Legends are only collapsed together if they have the same title and labels.  You changed the title and labels for `fill` and not `color`, hence getting two legends instead of a single collapsed legend.  If you only want a `fill` legend rather than a collapsed legend, you could use `guide = "none"` within `scale_color_discrete`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is remove the specific theme that is being created automatically by the aes specification. To do this add the line:

```
scale_fill(guide = 'none')
```

to your code. At other times you may need to do this for other aesthetics you add to your plot. In that case just use the appropriate `scale_`command